# httpClient doesn't retry the request

Tags: android

I'm using the spring android rest template 1.0.0.M2 version, I need to set the request time out and the retry attempt. I did it in following way.

```
//Time out
   httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(5000);
   restTemplate.setRequestFactory(httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory);

//set the reattempt   
client.setHttpRequestRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(retryCount, false));
```

Problem is when read time out occurs it's not retry the request again. Can some one help me on this.

Thanks
Sam.

Answer (score 0):

There's [an example in spring android showcase](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-android-samples/blob/master/spring-android-showcase/client/src/org/springframework/android/showcase/rest/HttpGetSetRequestTimeoutActivity.java), have you checked that? Because [a reported bug](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ANDROID-32) wasn't reproduced, problem may be somewhere else.